# Is there anyway to specify basicConstraints for openssl cert via command line

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'd like to include a `basicConstraints=CA:TRUE,pathlen:0` constraint in my self signed CA creation script and it would go a very long way to simplify my procedure if I didn't have to create a config file and all the folder structure of a proper CA.

I'm trying to create an intermediate cert that can only sign end certs, not further CAs. I will be using bouncycastle to sign all further certs, the folder structure I would need to create for a proper CA will not be used anyway.

Comment: It seems not the question about software development. Moreover you don't included the parameters which you use currently. Typically openssl.exe will automatically include the `basicConstraints` with `Subject Type=CA` and `Path Length Constraint=None` in the certificate. I tried `openssl ecparam -out myCA.key -name secp384r1 -genkey` and `openssl req -x509 -new -sha384 -key myCA.key -out myCA.pem -outform PEM -days 3650 -subj "/C=DE/O=OK soft GmbH/OU=Research/CN=CA Authority"`. One can add `-extensions v3_ca` to reference to `v3_ca` or default `openssl.cfg`, but one will have the same results.

Comment: I recommend you to verify that `req` section of your `openssl.cfg` contains `x509_extensions = v3_ca` entry. I suppose that you just creates the CA certificate in some other way (not using `openssl req ...`) and it's the reason of your problem.

Comment: I create the CA with this:

`openssl genrsa -des3 -out $KEYS_DIR/ca.key 4096`
`openssl req -new -x509 -days 36500 -key $KEYS_DIR/ca.key -out $KEYS_DIR/ca.crt` I was hoping there was a way to just add the basicConstraint to the second line

Comment: If I do the same on my computer I get ca.crt which have `Basic Constraints` with `Subject Type=CA` and `Path Length Constraint=None` like expected. You can view the content of the certificate by `openssl x509 -in test-ca.crt -text` or using `certutil -dump test-ca.crt` on Windows computers. Do you verified `openssl.cfg` which you use? Do you tried to add `-extensions v3_ca` option during creating the certificate?

Comment: I wanted to do it without the config file. The default config has either the `[ v3_req ]` configuration with `basicConstraints = CA:false` or `[ v3_ca ]` with `basicConstraints = CA:true`, I want a specific constraint above without using a config file.

Comment: Openssl always use default `openssl.cfg`. Do you verified with respect of `openssl x509 -in test-ca.crt -text` that there are really no `basicConstraints` in you certificate? If you create self-signed certificate then the section `[ v3_ca ]` with `basicConstraints = CA:true` should be automatically use. If you would sine the certificate with respect of *other certificate (openssl x509 -req ... -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial) then `[ v3_req ]``will be used.

Comment: Oh yes, ofcourse there are no constraints if I don't specify anything. They resultant cert is a CA cert that can sign other certs including other CAs. I would like to make a CA that cannot sign other CAs, only end certs.

Comment: The `basicConstraints = CA:true` or `basicConstraints=CA:TRUE,pathlen:0` do the same. The certificates which has the property can be used to sign certificates but no CA. It's standard requirement and thus it's default implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure why one should invest time in self-signed certificate today because there are good places like https://letsencrypt.org/ and https://startssl.com/ (see https://startssl.com/Validate) where one can get full trusted SSL certificate for free.

Comment: I want to sign client certs programmatically for client authentication. `openssl x509 -noout -text -in ~/tmp/intermediate.crt` is my intermediate cert signed directly by the selfsigned CA, output produces no constraints entry at all. `openssl x509 -noout -text -in ~/tmp/agent.crt` is my end cert signed by the intermediate cert. There are no constraint entries on it either. This is all on uptodate OSX.

Comment: Sorry I read [4.2.1.10  Basic Constraints](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2459#section-4.2.1.10) section of RFC 2459: "Where pathLenConstraint does not appear, there is no limit to the allowed length of the certification path." Thus you really need to add `Path Length Constraint=0` to prevent signing of CA.

Comment: Sorry, but all the discussion seems to me more and more far from the goal of stackoverflow (software development). I recommend you to post the question on http://serverfault.com/ (see http://serverfault.com/search?q=openssl) or http://security.stackexchange.com/ for example

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @jww "in my self signed CA creation script" the question is indeed about programming.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You do **not** need to create an OpenSSL configuration file, or any folder structure at all, to create a self-signed certificate using OpenSSL.

For example, here is what a minimal OpenSSL configuration file might  contain to set the basic constraints extension as you ask:

```
[req]
distinguished_name=dn
[ dn ]
[ ext ]
basicConstraints=CA:TRUE,pathlen:0
```

And here I create a self-signed certificate using OpenSSL from a Bash shell with this "configuration file", only, **it's not a file** -- it's a shell variable:

```
CONFIG="
[req]
distinguished_name=dn
[ dn ]
[ ext ]
basicConstraints=CA:TRUE,pathlen:0
"

openssl req -config <(echo "$CONFIG") -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes \
  -subj "/CN=Hello" -x509 -extensions ext -keyout key.pem -out crt.pem
```

Good luck!

Comment: It is a file. You just don't see it. But kudos for explicitly mentioning it to be a bashism.

Comment: Technically the ["Process Substitution" syntax](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) like `<( command_here )` is a way to create a **file descriptor** which most programs will read just as a normal file.  The `stdin`, & `stdout` pipes usually are easier if the program supports these.  However, some programs only expect files for some arguments.  So the great part is you can embed commands just like with backticks `\`command_here\``, or the dollar paren `$(command_here)` subshell syntax, and these programs will accept it as a "file". This only works in bash, not `/bin/sh`!

Answer (score 33):

### Adding `basicConstraints` without `openssl.cnf`

I couldn't see how to avoid using it entirely but using the default config and commenting out anything you set by commandline seems efficient enough.

#### Utilize `-addext` which can be used multiple times

Given an already-existing `privkey.pem` and with the caveat that *e.g.* `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` does not have conflicting instructions, the following seems to do it **without the bashism**.

```
DAYS='240'
SUBJECT='/CN=example.com/O=Example Co./OU=Engineering/L=Boston/ST=MA/C=US'
SERIAL='0x1001'

openssl req \
    -addext basicConstraints=critical,CA:TRUE,pathlen:1 \
    -outform pem -out cacert.pem \
    -key privkey.pem -new -x509 \
    -days "${DAYS}" \
    -subj "${SUBJECT}" \
    -set_serial "${SERIAL}"
```

Comment: Check the output with e.g. `openssl x509 -text -in cacert.pem` as it was fairly easy to set both `CRITICAL,CA:TRUE` and `CRITICAL,CA:FALSE` at the same time on the same certificate—stands to reason that could cause undefined behavior…

Comment: The `addext` option was introduced in OpenSSL 1.1.1.

Comment: I believe OpenSSL 1.1.1 adds `CRITICAL,CA:TRUE` by default... so if you add it again, with a different value, you are left with two extensions added :/ is there a `-removeext` option?

Comment: Figured it out. You need to comment out appropriate line in openssl.cnf

Comment: @PawełGościcki and which line is it?

Comment: One which says: `basicConstraints = critical,CA:true`