# Code signed with self-signed certificate basic constraint error

Tags: openssl, certificate

I want to get rid of Publisher: Unknown UAC message, for that I am trying to sign my .exe with a self-signed certificate (for testing purposes until I get a public one):

I generated certificate keys with the following command:

`.\openssl req -nodes -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -keyout key.pem -out crt.pem -subj "/CN=localhost" -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:localhost" -days 10000`

Then created .pfx:

`.\openssl pkcs12 -inkey key.pem -in crt.pem -export -out MyCert.pfx`

Imported the certificate into Trusted Root Authorities:

[image]

After that I signed my code file:

`signtool sign /f "MyCert.pfx" /p 1234 /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com?td=sha256 /td sha256 /as /v "CodeSignTest1.exe"`

But when I open file properties, I see the following errors:

[image]

How to fix that? Is it possible at all to use self-signed certificate for code signing? I'm on Windows 10.

PS: If I create a certificate using this command `$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DNSName "www.domain.com" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -Type CodeSigningCert -Subject "Example Code Signing Certificate"`, it works. But I wonder what's wrong with openssl statement.

Answer (score 1):

The basic constraints extension is missing. See [Is there anyway to specify basicConstraints for openssl cert via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920558/is-there-anyway-to-specify-basicconstraints-for-openssl-cert-via-command-line) for the config file or command line arguments to add it.

As you don't want a CA certificate you might want to use `-addext basicConstraints=critical,CA:FALSE,pathlen:0`