# Self-Signed certificate: openssl 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)

Tags: go, https, openssl, ubuntu-18.04, self-signed-certificate

I have created a self-signed certificate in `azure`.

The certificate is installed on an ubuntu machine.
Process:

```
sudo -s
cp <cert> /usr/share/ca-certificates
dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

`dpkg-reconfigure` shows gui.

[image]

I select yes to trust the certificate. On the next page, I see a list of certificates. I select my certificate (by pressing `space` key) and press `ok` (`tab` -> `enter`)

The certificate is added successfully.

But when I run `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <server>:<port>`, I get `Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)`

I have tested this localhost (mac OS X). It works after I set `Always Trust` for `When using this certificate` under `Trust` section of the certificate. (Certificate locally is created directly using openssl commands)

```
openssl req  -new  -newkey rsa:2048  -nodes  -keyout localhost.key  -out localhost.csr
openssl  x509  -req  -days 365  -in localhost.csr  -signkey localhost.key  -out localhost.crt
```

I'm running a Golang server where this certificate is used with the key vai `http.ListenAndServeTLS` function.

The process on mac is really simply. Just drag and drop the certificate in the `Keychain Access` and trust the certificate.

This is a major blocker for me. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Please check that a) the certificate shown in the output of s_client is exactly the one you trusted and b) that the certificate has basic constraints CA:true, i.e. is a CA certificate (use `openssl x509 -in file.csr -text`)

Comment: The certificate shown is the one I trusted. But, I see CA:FALSE.How can I turn that to true?

Comment: This is a self-signed certificate. Maybe that's why CA is set to false? How can I have a self-signed certificate on the trusted list for it to work?

Comment: self-signed certificates can be created with CA:true and CA:false. openssl requires a trusted __CA__ though for verification, which means that the self-signed certificate must be a CA, i.e. CA:true.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the link and the explanation. They are very helpful and answers most of it. You mentioned here "self-signed certificates can be created with CA:true and CA:false". Could you guide me on how (what command) can I use to generate a self-signed certificate with CA:true, please? I'm hoping this will resolve the issue of the OpenSSL 21 error and the Go server would start working as expected.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920558/is-there-anyway-to-specify-basicconstraints-for-openssl-cert-via-command-line

Comment: The way azure is done, I can't use the DNS provided by them. I had to get a custom domain. Then host that domain on azure, get the cert for the custom domain, install the cert on ubuntu. It's working now.

Comment: Btw, Steffen the command you gave `openssl x509 -in file.crt -text` came really handy. Many thanks for that.